# JS Array of object, filter by existing items in same array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to filter this array, condition: if programParent property exists in another object id, that object must be ignored. This is what i coded for now, i need some help. Thanks in advance.

```js
let programs = [
    { id: '23', name: 'a', programParent: '111' },
    { id: '24', name: 'a', programParent: '112' },
    { id: '25', name: 'a', programParent: '113' },
    { id: '26', name: 'a', programParent: '24' },
    { id: '27', name: 'a', programParent: '25' },
    { id: '28', name: 'a', programParent: '111' },
    { id: '29', name: 'a', programParent: '28' }
]


let options = programs.filter(x => programs.some(y => y !== x.programParent))
console.log(options)


expected = [
    { id: '23', name: 'a', programParent: '111' },
    { id: '24', name: 'a', programParent: '112' },
    { id: '25', name: 'a', programParent: '113' },
    { id: '28', name: 'a', programParent: '111' }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your filter condition is wrong

```
programs.filter(x => programs.some(y => y !== x.programParent))
```

First of all, you probably want to use `y.id !==` instead of `y` But also the semantics of `some` doesn't fit here, because that literally means: "Keep those elements `x`, where there exists at least one program `y` with `y.id !== x.programParent` And that condition is obviously true for every single element, because `y.id` is different for every element.

Use

```
programs.filter(x => !programs.find(y => y.id == x.programParent))
```

instead, which means "Keep those elements `x` where no element `y` can be found with `y.id == x.programParent`

You can also do it with, `some` but you need to invert the result of `some` and use a `==` condition, ie `!some(x == y) == none(x == y)`

```
programs.filter(x => !programs.some(y => y.id == x.programParent))
```

Or you can use `every`, then you can keep your `!==` condition, ie ie `every(x != y) == none(x == y)`

```
programs.filter(x => programs.every(y => y.id != x.programParent))
```

To sum up: All three filters I've shown are equivalent. Take the one you like most. But when using `some` or `every` you have to be clear about their semantics and how you must define the condtion, so that they fit your needed semantics ...